# Why my phpmyadmin is downloading a file called 'download'?

Tags: phpmyadmin

It seems my phpmyadmin is downloading a file called 'downlaod' everytime I visit mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin. I tried this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04) but then I was getting 403 forbidden, now it is downlaoding a file called 'download'.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I think the file downloaded is `index.php` for phpmyadmin. Also, I'm using nginx server.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin requires a PHP-enabled web server.

Comment: I installed php, here's the [info](https://hostitor.com/info.php)